# What happens if a shugenja takes the Multiple Schools advantage to join another shugenja school?

Tags: l5r-4e

This is a strictly mechanical question. Obviously, when switching schools shugenja would gain access to the new technique, however are there any additional advantages or penalties to do so? Do they gain a new affinity/deficiency? Do they gain the 6 starting spells scrolls for the school? Do shugenja School Ranks stack for purposes of learning and casting spells? Otherwise do they have to choose which School Rank to cast spells with based on where they learned it or do they just use the highest?

**Does it say anywhere in the RAW about what happens to shugenja if they move to another shugenja school?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found nothing in the books. However, in a post in the errata & rules thread in the now defunct Alderac forums<sup>†</sup>, one player asked about this issue and he was provided an answer. If this can be considered RAW, then, according to that post, when a shugenja takes multiple schools and gains a new rank, this is what happens:

- Her Shugenja School rank increases by 1 (not resets). A Shugenja does not have a separate school rank for each school she has attended.
- She gains the technique of her new school.
- She gain the affinity and deficiency of the new school (affinities and
  deficiencies stack).
- She gain 3 new spells.

---

† Editor note: the forum post in question unfortunately seems to be lost. This is the link if anyone feels like spelunking:

http://www.alderac.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=250&t=84283&p=1340061&hilit=multiple%20schools#p1340061

Comment: I consider errata to be RAW, though I can see why others might not. Thank you. This was exactly the sort of information I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry for necroing this, but are Shugenja School rank tracked separately for School Techniques? For example, the Asahina Shugenja School allows you to reduce opponents' damage for a number of rounds equal to your ***School Rank***. Would a Rank 1 Asahina Shugenja / Rank 1 Kuni Shugenja reduce damage for 1 round, or 2 rounds?

Comment: @Cristol.GdM It last for 2 Rounds. Shugenja do not have a separate school rank for each school she has attended. They have a single school rank, and the benefits (and penalties) associated to each school just stack.